# Total duration of the route with time windows is not optimal

Tags: optaplanner

I prepared a test case illustrating the problem.
The [route](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PaATw.png) consists of three points:

```
1001 - depot. 
1002 - timewindow 10:00-15:00. 
1003 - timewindow 8:00-15:00.
```

I expected that the route will be 1001-1003-1002, but received 1001-1002-1003.

As I understand, soft score constraint doesn't optimize downtime interval = `readyTime - arrivalTime`.

Although total travel time is minimal (calculated only by the matrix), but the total duration of the route now is more than could be.

Can I somehow optimize total route duration?
Thanks in advance.

Vrp file:

```
NAME: P1568C3-n3-k1
COMMENT: P1568C3-n3-k1
TYPE: CVRPTW
DIMENSION: 3
EDGE_WEIGHT_TYPE: EXPLICIT
EDGE_WEIGHT_FORMAT: FULL_MATRIX
EDGE_WEIGHT_UNIT_OF_MEASUREMENT: SEC
CAPACITY: 4
NODE_COORD_SECTION
1001 52.086 23.687 address
1002 52.089 23.71 address
1003 52.095 23.742 address
EDGE_WEIGHT_SECTION
0 0.1675 0.4053 
0.1675 0 0.2378 
0.4893 0.3218 0 
DEMAND_SECTION
1001 0 21600 54000 0
1002 1 36000 54000 1800
1003 1 28800 54000 1800
DEPOT_SECTION
1001
-1
EOF
```

Result xml:

```
  <vehicleList id="11">
    <VrpVehicle id="12">
      <id>0</id>
      <capacity>4</capacity>
      <depot class="VrpTimeWindowedDepot" reference="10"/>
      <nextCustomer class="VrpTimeWindowedCustomer" id="13">
        <id>1002</id>
        <location class="VrpRoadLocation" reference="5"/>
        <demand>1</demand>
        <previousStandstill class="VrpVehicle" reference="12"/>
        <nextCustomer class="VrpTimeWindowedCustomer" id="14">
          <id>1003</id>
          <location class="VrpRoadLocation" reference="7"/>
          <demand>1</demand>
          <previousStandstill class="VrpTimeWindowedCustomer" reference="13"/>
          <vehicle reference="12"/>
          <readyTime>28800</readyTime>
          <dueTime>54000</dueTime>
          <serviceDuration>1800</serviceDuration>
          <arrivalTime>38038</arrivalTime>
        </nextCustomer>
        <vehicle reference="12"/>
        <readyTime>36000</readyTime>
        <dueTime>54000</dueTime>
        <serviceDuration>1800</serviceDuration>
        <arrivalTime>36000</arrivalTime>
      </nextCustomer>
    </VrpVehicle>
  </vehicleList>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `optaplanner-examples` implementation, which follows the academic paper's problem definition, the score implementation soft score is only the time spend on the road. **The current score constraints do not include any penalty for lost time (if any) of vehicles before leaving the depot.**

You can see that in the example UI if you click on the bottom left button "constraint matches":

- -489 for driving back to the depot
- -406: -168 for driving from the depot to closest customer and -238 to drive to other customer.

**So OptaPlanner does return the optimal solution,** you just have a different problem definition. Simply add a soft constraint to penalize the depot's opening time till the departure time.

Comment: Note that your data is weird, as it takes 18% longer to drive from C to A then it does to drive from A to C through B. That's unlikely due to triangle inequality (but possible in the real world though).

Comment: I have done as you have written and now everything is working as it should, in accordance with my problem definition.
New soft constraint:
`rule "depotOpeningTime"
    when
        $customer : TimeWindowedCustomer(previousStandstill != null, $arrivalTime : arrivalTime)
        not TimeWindowedCustomer(previousStandstill == $customer)
    then
        scoreHolder.addSoftConstraintMatch(kcontext, - $arrivalTime.longValue());
end`
Thank you very much!
@GeoffreyDeSmet